# How to migrate from Zefyr to Fleather package? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, text-editor, quill

I was used Zefyr package, and now migrate to Fleather package **(zefyr's authors advised that)**
but fleather can't read old documents which wrote with zefyr.
is any solution for this problem instead of using replaceAll function ?

using replaceAll function to documents
it takes a lot of time

There are most of the keys were changed like "bold", "italic", "underline", ...
changed with "b", "i", "u", ...
also video, image, collapsible, divider

> fleather wrote video and image like that:

```
{
        "insert": {
            "source": "https://...",
            "_type": "image",
            "_inline": false
        }
    },
    {
        "insert": {
            "source": "https://www.youtube.com/...",
            "_type": "video",
            "_inline": false
        }
    }
```

> but zfyre wrote it like that:

```
{
    "insert": "​",
    "attributes": {
      "embed": {
        "type": "image",
        "source": "https://..."
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "insert": "​",
    "attributes": {
      "embed": {
        "type": "video",
        "source": "https://www.youtube.com/..."
      }
    }
  }
```

I try to write code to convert zefyr document to fleather, I will publish it soon.

Comment: Can you share a document you've created using `zefyr`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.